# Hive remove comma from end

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have column values at end of each string,e.g.

```
Column_Name
---------------------
bottle,need,beer,
same,ruler,cat,
```

and i want result like:

```
bottle,need,beer
same,ruler,cat
```

Is there any function present in hive to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the comma is present at the end of every value in the column, you could use `substr` to remove the last character:

```
select substr(column_name, 1, length(column_name) - 1) from t
```

Comment: `select substr(column_name, 1, length(column_name) - x) from t`. It's a more generic approach to remove  ' x'  number of chars from right. Where x is `int`. Good one @Gurwinder Singh